# PHP passthru('cls') not working

Tags: php

I'm a newbie for PHP in command line. I'm using windows and I want to clear the screen in command line. I've searched it and found this code

`<?php passthru('cls'); ?>`

But this code instead of clearing the screen, it shows this character '♀'. I've also tried using `shell_exec` and `exec`, but they failed. Did I do anything wrong? How do I fix this?

Thanks :D

Comment: Does `cls` work in that same command line without `php` running in it? Seems like the control code wasn't interpreted by the terminal emulator.

Comment: yes, it works without `php`. I've tried using a random command and it shows the same error message as the command line. Also I tried using `passthru('echo hello');` and it works, it shows "hello".

Comment: `passthru` creates a separate process and executes the command there; whatever screen this tries to clear (possibly none) won't be the one you're looking at.  While you do get the raw output from a command with `passthru`, I doubt there's much interesting output from the `cls` command; more likely it invokes some special behavior of the terminal program.

Comment: @FoolishSeth That should be an answer.

Comment: @deceze It's only half an answer; I have no idea how to actually do the cls in the current window.

Comment: @FoolishSeth it should be sending an escape sequence to the underlying device. `clear` works as expected, clearing the same pty `php` is running in, regardless of forks, the descriptors are shared in `passthru`.

Comment: @DarwinGautalius what shell are you running? I would try `echo chr(27).'[H'.chr(27).'[2J';` from `php` directly; or `passthru( 'echo ' . chr(27).'[H'.chr(27).'[2J' );` as per ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: I'm running in Windows shell. I've tried to use `passthru('clear');` and it doesn't work as expected since i'm using windows.

Comment: You mean `cmd.exe`? Try the escape sequences, too. `clear` works perfectly well in `xterm` (didn't expect it to be available in Windows of course) and so do the above ANSI escape codes for clear screen. Not expecting them to work http://superuser.com/questions/249128/coloring-windows-xp-cmd-exe but who knows.

Comment: Also try `system()` as `passthru()` seems to suppress `STDERR` in Windows.

Comment: yes, i use `cmd.exe`. Sorry, I don't understand what u meant to try the escape sequences. What should I do to try this?

Comment: Some other interesting thoughts here http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=397079 regarding how `cls` is not a binary, but rather an internal shell trickery. Read my comment above regarding ANSI escape sequences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667745/php-passthrucls-not-working#comment18759446_13667745

Comment: I've tried using `system()` before i found passthru function because I think php have many similar function as `C`. It also shows character '♀' like the function `passthru()` do.

Comment: I've tried using both `echo chr(27).'[H'.chr(27).'[2J';` and `passthru( 'echo ' . chr(27).'[H'.chr(27).'[2J' );`. Both shows the same character '←[H←[2J'. what does it mean?

Comment: That ANSI escape codes are not supported by `cmd.exe`; try creating a shell script with `cls` inside and running it instead, perhaps not being able to find a `cls.exe` is the real issue here, as `passthru` or `system` do not create a new `cmd.exe` context, or perhaps even `system( 'cmd /c cls' )`? Experiment around it should be possible.

Comment: According to [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Clear_the_screen) currently there is no way to do it in php

Comment: @soulseekah Do you mean I create a bat file with cls inside and call it using cmd? I've tried `cmd /c cls` directly in `cmd.exe` and it shows the same character '♀'. Does it mean that running php script will create a new instance of `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller So it's not possible in php? but many forums have successfully done this (if i don't misunderstand).

Comment: Running out of easy experiments fast; last thing to try is to actually write a C application leveraging the WinAPI, like http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/216489/clear-the-screen-using-winapi-functions perhaps. I wouldn't be surprised if it actually worked. It works in so many languages. Other than that, changing terminal emulators may be your best option.

Comment: I've tried using C from your link in daniweb.com and also use `system('cls');` like I usually use. Both of them are worked.
So, is it not possible to do this? Then, I'll give up trying this. hahaha. btw, thanks for your time helping me. :D

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I finally found an answer that works for me in Windows 7 that relies on ANSI (like the comments above):

```
echo chr(27)."[H".chr(27)."[2J";
```

This works for me in the standard console ***because I installed [Ansicon](http://adoxa.altervista.org/ansicon)***, which appears to be what you're missing... if you're having trouble you might also want to try [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console).